# Layered Navigation Extension with Manageable Meta Description and Title for active filter

Tags: magento2, extensions

We are looking for a layered navigation extension that can have a specific Meta Description and title when a filter is active. Already, a bunch of layered navigation extensions are available, which add the feature of multi selection of filters, but we couldn't find one for the feature we are looking for.

For example, we have a category for Shirts and title can be "Buy shirts online". when filter for color blue is active, title should be "Buy Blue Shirts Online".